# pgAdmin - Cannot dump file, "aborting because of server version mismatch"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

**My situation**

I received my database from a different laptop that had an old version of PostgresSQL/pgAdmin. I restored it into a different laptop with the most updated version of PostgreSQL/pgAdmin. I made some changes to the database and now an error appears when I want to dump it.

**The error is saying:**

```
pg_dump: error: server version: 14.1; pg_dump version: 13.4.
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

**My binary path in pgAdmin**

[image: My binary path in pg admin]

I am unsure why my versions are different. Shouldn't both versions be updated when PostgreSQL is updated?  What can I do to fix this issue?

EDIT:

**MY OS**: Windows

**PGAdmin version**: 5.7

**Changes I made**: simple ALTER and CREATE TABLE queries

Comment: your local binary's either not updated or pointing to older one. export latest bin location

Comment: What is your OS?  How did you install things? What is your version of pgAdmin4? *What* changes did you make to the database?

Comment: I think you're using an older version of pgAdmin. The latest version has the binaries for pg-14.

Comment: @AdityaToshniwal Thank you! your solution worked :)! I was using an older version of pgadmin for some reason. Would you want to post it as an answer I can mark it as a solution and others can see it :) ?

Comment: @MatthewFrancis If it fixes it, then sure you can mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AdityaToshniwal's comment, I was able to fix it:

> "I think you're using an older version of pgAdmin. The latest version
> has the binaries for pg-14."

I was using an older version of pgadmin